# Java 9, INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR when trying to add URL as element in XML

Tags: java, xml

I'm working with XML for the first time, trying to generate XML to send over to a client and I'm having a hell of a time doing it. Whenever I try to pass a URL, I get an INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR and nothing I've tried so far works.

I tried using replacements like & #123; and so on for the curly braces, and tried escaping everything that wasn't a letter, resulting in the abomination under my code. It seems to throw the error if I have any kind of character that isn't a letter. Another thing that I noticed is that the document's InputEncoding is null, but that seems to be because I'm creating it in code, does that mean that it actually doesn't have an encoding type? I haven't been able to find an easy way to set it either.

````
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document orders = dBuilder.newDocument();
            Element order = orders.createElement("{https://secure.targeturl.com/foo/bar}tagpayload");
            Element tOrder = orders.createElement("tagorder");
            order.appendChild(tOrder);
            Element header = orders.createElement("orderheader");
            tOrder.appendChild(header);
            Element billto = orders.createElement("billto");
            header.appendChild(billto); ```


``` "& #123;https& #58;& #47;& #47;secure& #46;targeturl& #46;com&#47;foo& #47;bar& #125;tagpayload" ```
````

Comment: As far as imports are using, they're
 ```javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException; 
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

Comment: Hey, congrats on your first question! Please accept the answer if it solved your problem, thanks.

Comment: Added a comment to accept the answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to create a namespaced element:

```
Element order = orders.createElement("{https://secure.targeturl.com/foo/bar}tagpayload");
```

Instead, use the [createElementNS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElementNS(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) method:

```
Element order = orders.createElementNS("https://secure.targeturl.com/foo/bar", "tagpayload");
```

You are seeing an exception because `{` is not a legal character in an XML element name.  `createElement` has no awareness of namespaces or the “{uri}name” namespace notation.